Weird behavior of C#12 with explicit overrided conversion operator (how can I know about which one is called)
I'm looking for a way to find out why an implicit conversion is happening, even though I don't have one in my code at all. Thus, I expected to find a method that would show which type in the code there is an explicit overloading method that I had not noticed, in order to find it and correct this error. The UnixTime overload converts int to UnixTime, and long->UnixTime does not exist. So I don't understand what's going on at all. And I would like to ask about methods for finding such an error.
As far as I know long cannot be implicitly converted to int. And here a similar conversion occurs - since I do not have any overloaded method or constructor with a long parameter and an int parameter on the output, or any other combinations with implicit conversions that the compiler could automatically substitute. Also, I expected to see the name of the overloaded method so I could fix it and make it explicit
I compiled this method
public AccountInfo(SQLFields fields, int startColumn)
{
    Id = fields.Read<int>(startColumn + 0);
    Name = fields.Read<string>(startColumn + 1);
    UnbanDate = (DateTime)(UnixTime)fields.Read<long>(startColumn + 2); //this line
    IsPermanenetlyBanned = fields.Read<int>(startColumn + 3) != 0;
    IsBanned = IsPermanenetlyBanned || UnbanDate > Time.Now;
    SecurityLevel = (AccountTypes)fields.Read<byte>(startColumn + 4);

    int hashPos = Name.IndexOf('#');
    if (hashPos != -1)
        DisplayName = "WoW" + Name[(hashPos + 1)..];
    else
        DisplayName = Name;

    CharacterCounts = new Dictionary<uint, byte>();
    LastPlayedCharacters = new Dictionary<string, LastPlayedCharacterInfo>();
}

and took this:
// UnbanDate = (DateTime)(UnixTime)(int)fields.Read<long>(startColumn + 2);
    IL_0024: ldarg.0
    IL_0025: ldarg.1
    IL_0026: ldarg.2
    IL_0027: ldc.i4.2
    IL_0028: add
    IL_0029: callvirt instance !!0 [Framework]Framework.Database.SQLFields::Read<int64>(int32)
    IL_002e: conv.i4
    IL_002f: call valuetype [Framework]UnixTime [Framework]UnixTime::op_Explicit(int32)
    IL_0034: call valuetype [System.Runtime]System.DateTime [Framework]UnixTime::op_Explicit(valuetype [Framework]UnixTime)
    IL_0039: stfld valuetype [System.Runtime]System.DateTime BNetServer.Networking.GameAccountInfo::UnbanDate

But i can't see any call of int::op_Explicit, just conv.i4
Why, what is happening here? How can I reveal about this behaviour?
See more : there

im sure IL has some built in intrinsic functions like casting to various integer types which int32 == i4

Isn't IL an implementation detail? Why are you worried about this? What is the issue exactly? Is your code not working? OTherwise... I feel like this just cannot be answered by any "normal" person in SO:

As far as I know long cannot be implicitly converted to int.
And here a similar conversion occurs - since I do not have any overloaded method or constructor with a long parameter and an int parameter on the output, or any other combinations with implicit conversions that the compiler could automatically substitute.
Also, I expected to see the name of the overloaded method so I could fix it and make it explicit

AFAIK C# can "chain" conversions in some cases, for example the following:
UnixTime Do(long i)
{
    UnixTime x = (UnixTime)i;    
    return x;
}

class UnixTime
{
    public static explicit operator UnixTime(int i) => new UnixTime();
}

is treated like:
var x = (UnixTime)(int)i;

and `conv.i4 is:

Converts the value on top of the evaluation stack to int32.

Which is standard explicit conversion for int and long (so there is no op_Explicit there, which AFAIK denotes user-defined explicit conversion).
If I understand the specification correctly, the these are relevant parts:

10.5.5 User-defined explicit conversions
A user-defined explicit conversion from an expression E to a type T is processed as follows:
...

Find the set of applicable user-defined and lifted conversion operators, U. This set consists of the user-defined and lifted implicit or explicit conversion operators declared by the classes or structs in D that convert from a type encompassing E or encompassed by S (if it exists) to a type encompassing or encompassed by T
...
Finally, apply the conversion:

If E does not already have the type Sₓ, then a standard explicit conversion from E to Sₓ is performed.
The most-specific user-defined conversion operator is invoked to convert from Sₓ to Tₓ.
If Tₓ is not T, then a standard explicit conversion from Tₓ to T is performed.




So, if I understand it correctly when compiler is processing explicit conversion from long to UnixTime it finds that there is user-defined explicit conversion int -> UnixTime and standard explicit conversion long -> int it chains them.
Also answer to Chaining implicit operators in generic c# classes can be an interesting read also.

I thought about this too. But the point is that the compiler never makes 2 implicit conversions for the same type at once. But it can convert both operands once each to a common type.
And as it turns out, all these types have a common type - float. Look at the link to the bug report - you can clearly see how this happens.

then why doesn’t this rule always work?

@Artem what do you mean by "why doesn’t this rule always work?"?

I mean "Why if I do it with int->ulong - C# make an error. More info on github/issues

@Artem u ones are interesting, yes, float/decimal for example work fine, it seems that there is nuance which I don't yet understand (maybe your remark about float is correct). Or bug =)

this looks like a bug that was left for the sake of compatibility with older versions

The code is correct, you're casting the result of fields.Read<long>(startColumn + 2) (which is long) to an int, and casting is done using the conv.type IL instruction. Read your line:
UnbanDate = (DateTime)(UnixTime)(int)fields.Read<long>(startColumn + 2);

After that you're constructing objects by "casting" them to UnixTime and DateTime respectively, which is implemented as explicit cast operators.

As far as I know long cannot be implicitly converted to int.
And here a similar conversion occurs - since I do not have any overloaded method or constructor with a long parameter and an int parameter on the output, or any other combinations with implicit conversions that the compiler could automatically substitute.
Also, I expected to see the name of the overloaded method so I could fix it and make it explicit

long isn't implicitly converted to int, it's explicitly cast. Didn't you write that code? (int)fields.Read<long>(startColumn + 2) Casts are explicit conversions.

this code after compiling, so it is not my feature, i didn't use this conversation explicitly

I was just expecting to see the name of the overloaded method in the IL code)) that’s why the question is “If I don’t see the name of this method, how will I know what happened here without my will?” The code was compiled with optimization disabled. There were no errors during compilation.

What method name are you looking for? They're all listed in your output. Specifically, the integer is used as a parameter to UnixTime::op_Explicit(int32), a user defined function.

this is the next operation. First long was converted to int without my consent (conv.i4)

Right but this isn't Rust, compiler intrinsics like casts (implicit or otherwise) don't have method names. So again, what method name are you asking about? If your answer is still the cast then you're wasting your time.

I'm looking for a way to find out why an implicit conversion is happening, even though I don't have one in my code at all. Thus, I expected to find a method that would show which type in the code there is an explicit overloading method that I had not noticed, in order to find it and correct this error. The UnixTime overload converts int to UnixTime, and long->UnixTime does not exist. So I don't understand what's going on at all. And I would like to ask about methods for finding such an error.

The implicit conversion is most likely a bug, you won't find (and are unable to even write anything like it in C#) an implicit int operator under the long type.

I tried - it bugged with other types also
[short to int]
[ushort to uint]
[ushort to long]
[ushort to ulong]
[short to long]
[short to ulong]
and etc

@Blindy AFAIK this is not a bug but a feature.
